# JPA @OneToMany annotation is looping

Tags: json, spring-boot, jpa, spring-restcontroller

I'm using JPA and MySql I created 3 tables with relations @OneToMany and @ManyToOne. I'm trying to get data about records from table which have described relations. After trying to get data I got this error SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unterminated string literal at line 1 column 183719 of the JSON data. I just see a lot of records from gp_contractor table. When I use @JsonIgnore to relation with gp_contractor I can get all data from table gp_invoice and gp_invoiceitem. I have no idea what is wrong.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "gp_contractor")
public class GpContractor {
    private int mGpContractorRecid;
    private String mGpContractorName;
    private String mGpContractorNip;
    private String mGpContractorStreet;
    private String mGpContractorHouseNumber;
    private String mGpContractorFlatNumber;
    private String mGpContractorZipCode;
    private String mGpContractorCity;
    private Collection<GpInvoice> mGpInvoicesByGpContractorRecid;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "GP_CONTRACTOR_RECID", nullable = false)
    public int getGpContractorRecid() {
        return mGpContractorRecid;
    }

    public void setGpContractorRecid(int gpContractorRecid) {
        mGpContractorRecid = gpContractorRecid;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "GP_CONTRACTOR_NAME", nullable = false, length = 50)
    public String getGpContractorName() {
        return mGpContractorName;
    }

    public void setGpContractorName(String gpContractorName) {
        mGpContractorName = gpContractorName;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "GP_CONTRACTOR_NIP", nullable = false, length = 10)
    public String getGpContractorNip() {
        return mGpContractorNip;
    }

    public void setGpContractorNip(String gpContractorNip) {
        mGpContractorNip = gpContractorNip;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "GP_CONTRACTOR_STREET", nullable = false, length = 50)
    public String getGpContractorStreet() {
        return mGpContractorStreet;
    }

    public void setGpContractorStreet(String gpContractorStreet) {
        mGpContractorStreet = gpContractorStreet;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "GP_CONTRACTOR_HOUSE_NUMBER", nullable = false, length = 10)
    public String getGpContractorHouseNumber() {
        return mGpContractorHouseNumber;
    }

    public void setGpContractorHouseNumber(String gpContractorHouseNumber) {
        mGpContractorHouseNumber = gpContractorHouseNumber;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "GP_CONTRACTOR_FLAT_NUMBER", nullable = true, length = 10)
    public String getGpContractorFlatNumber() {
        return mGpContractorFlatNumber;
    }

    public void setGpContractorFlatNumber(String gpContractorFlatNumber) {
        mGpContractorFlatNumber = gpContractorFlatNumber;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "GP_CONTRACTOR_ZIP_CODE", nullable = false, length = 10)
    public String getGpContractorZipCode() {
        return mGpContractorZipCode;
    }

    public void setGpContractorZipCode(String gpContractorZipCode) {
        mGpContractorZipCode = gpContractorZipCode;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "GP_CONTRACTOR_CITY", nullable = false, length = 50)
    public String getGpContractorCity() {
        return mGpContractorCity;
    }

    public void setGpContractorCity(String gpContractorCity) {
        mGpContractorCity = gpContractorCity;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        GpContractor that = (GpContractor) o;
        return mGpContractorRecid == that.mGpContractorRecid &&
                Objects.equals(mGpContractorName, that.mGpContractorName) &&
                Objects.equals(mGpContractorNip, that.mGpContractorNip) &&
                Objects.equals(mGpContractorStreet, that.mGpContractorStreet) &&
                Objects.equals(mGpContractorHouseNumber, that.mGpContractorHouseNumber) &&
                Objects.equals(mGpContractorFlatNumber, that.mGpContractorFlatNumber) &&
                Objects.equals(mGpContractorZipCode, that.mGpContractorZipCode) &&
                Objects.equals(mGpContractorCity, that.mGpContractorCity);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(mGpContractorRecid, mGpContractorName, mGpContractorNip, mGpContractorStreet, mGpContractorHouseNumber, mGpContractorFlatNumber, mGpContractorZipCode, mGpContractorCity);
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "gpContractorByGpInvoiceContractor")
    public Collection<GpInvoice> getGpInvoicesByGpContractorRecid() {
        return mGpInvoicesByGpContractorRecid;
    }

    public void setGpInvoicesByGpContractorRecid(Collection<GpInvoice> gpInvoicesByGpContractorRecid) {
        mGpInvoicesByGpContractorRecid = gpInvoicesByGpContractorRecid;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "gp_invoice")
public class GpInvoice {
    private int mGpInvoiceRecid;
    private String mGpInvoiceTitle;
    private String mGpInvoiceNumber;
    private Date mGpInvoiceRelease;
    private Date mGpInvoicePosting;
    private Date mGpInvoiceDelivery;
    private String mGpInvoiceReleaseplace;
    private GpContractor mGpContractorByGpInvoiceContractor;
    private Collection<GpInvoiceitem> mGpInvoiceitemsByGpInvoiceRecid;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "GP_INVOICE_RECID", nullable = false)
    public int getGpInvoiceRecid() {
        return mGpInvoiceRecid;
    }

    public void setGpInvoiceRecid(int gpInvoiceRecid) {
        mGpInvoiceRecid = gpInvoiceRecid;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "GP_INVOICE_TITLE", nullable = false, length = 50)
    public String getGpInvoiceTitle() {
        return mGpInvoiceTitle;
    }

    public void setGpInvoiceTitle(String gpInvoiceTitle) {
        mGpInvoiceTitle = gpInvoiceTitle;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "GP_INVOICE_NUMBER", nullable = false, length = 50)
    public String getGpInvoiceNumber() {
        return mGpInvoiceNumber;
    }

    public void setGpInvoiceNumber(String gpInvoiceNumber) {
        mGpInvoiceNumber = gpInvoiceNumber;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "GP_INVOICE_RELEASE", nullable = false)
    public Date getGpInvoiceRelease() {
        return mGpInvoiceRelease;
    }

    public void setGpInvoiceRelease(Date gpInvoiceRelease) {
        mGpInvoiceRelease = gpInvoiceRelease;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "GP_INVOICE_POSTING", nullable = true)
    public Date getGpInvoicePosting() {
        return mGpInvoicePosting;
    }

    public void setGpInvoicePosting(Date gpInvoicePosting) {
        mGpInvoicePosting = gpInvoicePosting;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "GP_INVOICE_DELIVERY", nullable = false)
    public Date getGpInvoiceDelivery() {
        return mGpInvoiceDelivery;
    }

    public void setGpInvoiceDelivery(Date gpInvoiceDelivery) {
        mGpInvoiceDelivery = gpInvoiceDelivery;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "GP_INVOICE_RELEASEPLACE", nullable = false, length = 50)
    public String getGpInvoiceReleaseplace() {
        return mGpInvoiceReleaseplace;
    }

    public void setGpInvoiceReleaseplace(String gpInvoiceReleaseplace) {
        mGpInvoiceReleaseplace = gpInvoiceReleaseplace;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        GpInvoice gpInvoice = (GpInvoice) o;
        return mGpInvoiceRecid == gpInvoice.mGpInvoiceRecid &&
                Objects.equals(mGpInvoiceTitle, gpInvoice.mGpInvoiceTitle) &&
                Objects.equals(mGpInvoiceNumber, gpInvoice.mGpInvoiceNumber) &&
                Objects.equals(mGpInvoiceRelease, gpInvoice.mGpInvoiceRelease) &&
                Objects.equals(mGpInvoicePosting, gpInvoice.mGpInvoicePosting) &&
                Objects.equals(mGpInvoiceDelivery, gpInvoice.mGpInvoiceDelivery) &&
                Objects.equals(mGpInvoiceReleaseplace, gpInvoice.mGpInvoiceReleaseplace);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(mGpInvoiceRecid, mGpInvoiceTitle, mGpInvoiceNumber, mGpInvoiceRelease, mGpInvoicePosting, mGpInvoiceDelivery, mGpInvoiceReleaseplace);
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "GP_INVOICE_CONTRACTOR", referencedColumnName = "GP_CONTRACTOR_RECID", nullable = false)
    public GpContractor getGpContractorByGpInvoiceContractor() {
        return mGpContractorByGpInvoiceContractor;
    }

    public void setGpContractorByGpInvoiceContractor(GpContractor gpContractorByGpInvoiceContractor) {
        mGpContractorByGpInvoiceContractor = gpContractorByGpInvoiceContractor;
    }


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "gpInvoiceByGpInvitInvoicerecid")
    public Collection<GpInvoiceitem> getGpInvoiceitemsByGpInvoiceRecid() {
        return mGpInvoiceitemsByGpInvoiceRecid;
    }

    public void setGpInvoiceitemsByGpInvoiceRecid(Collection<GpInvoiceitem> gpInvoiceitemsByGpInvoiceRecid) {
        mGpInvoiceitemsByGpInvoiceRecid = gpInvoiceitemsByGpInvoiceRecid;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "gp_invoiceitem")
public class GpInvoiceitem {
    private int mGpInvitRecid;
    private String mGpInvitName;
    private String mGpInvitDescription;
    private double mGpInvitPricenet;
    private int mGpInvitAmount;
    private String mGpInvitUnit;
    private int mGpInvitVat;
    private double mGpInvitPriceamountnet;
    private double mGpInvitPricevat;
    private double mGpInvitPricegross;
    private GpInvoice mGpInvoiceByGpInvitInvoicerecid;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "GP_INVIT_RECID", nullable = false)
    public int getGpInvitRecid() {
        return mGpInvitRecid;
    }

    public void setGpInvitRecid(int gpInvitRecid) {
        mGpInvitRecid = gpInvitRecid;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "GP_INVIT_NAME", nullable = false, length = 50)
    public String getGpInvitName() {
        return mGpInvitName;
    }

    public void setGpInvitName(String gpInvitName) {
        mGpInvitName = gpInvitName;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "GP_INVIT_DESCRIPTION", nullable = true, length = 200)
    public String getGpInvitDescription() {
        return mGpInvitDescription;
    }

    public void setGpInvitDescription(String gpInvitDescription) {
        mGpInvitDescription = gpInvitDescription;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "GP_INVIT_PRICENET", nullable = false, precision = 0)
    public double getGpInvitPricenet() {
        return mGpInvitPricenet;
    }

    public void setGpInvitPricenet(double gpInvitPricenet) {
        mGpInvitPricenet = gpInvitPricenet;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "GP_INVIT_AMOUNT", nullable = false)
    public int getGpInvitAmount() {
        return mGpInvitAmount;
    }

    public void setGpInvitAmount(int gpInvitAmount) {
        mGpInvitAmount = gpInvitAmount;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "GP_INVIT_UNIT", nullable = false, length = 10)
    public String getGpInvitUnit() {
        return mGpInvitUnit;
    }

    public void setGpInvitUnit(String gpInvitUnit) {
        mGpInvitUnit = gpInvitUnit;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "GP_INVIT_VAT", nullable = false)
    public int getGpInvitVat() {
        return mGpInvitVat;
    }

    public void setGpInvitVat(int gpInvitVat) {
        mGpInvitVat = gpInvitVat;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "GP_INVIT_PRICEAMOUNTNET", nullable = false, precision = 0)
    public double getGpInvitPriceamountnet() {
        return mGpInvitPriceamountnet;
    }

    public void setGpInvitPriceamountnet(double gpInvitPriceamountnet) {
        mGpInvitPriceamountnet = gpInvitPriceamountnet;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "GP_INVIT_PRICEVAT", nullable = false, precision = 0)
    public double getGpInvitPricevat() {
        return mGpInvitPricevat;
    }

    public void setGpInvitPricevat(double gpInvitPricevat) {
        mGpInvitPricevat = gpInvitPricevat;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "GP_INVIT_PRICEGROSS", nullable = false, precision = 0)
    public double getGpInvitPricegross() {
        return mGpInvitPricegross;
    }

    public void setGpInvitPricegross(double gpInvitPricegross) {
        mGpInvitPricegross = gpInvitPricegross;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        GpInvoiceitem that = (GpInvoiceitem) o;
        return mGpInvitRecid == that.mGpInvitRecid &&
                Double.compare(that.mGpInvitPricenet, mGpInvitPricenet) == 0 &&
                mGpInvitAmount == that.mGpInvitAmount &&
                mGpInvitVat == that.mGpInvitVat &&
                Double.compare(that.mGpInvitPriceamountnet, mGpInvitPriceamountnet) == 0 &&
                Double.compare(that.mGpInvitPricevat, mGpInvitPricevat) == 0 &&
                Double.compare(that.mGpInvitPricegross, mGpInvitPricegross) == 0 &&
                Objects.equals(mGpInvitName, that.mGpInvitName) &&
                Objects.equals(mGpInvitDescription, that.mGpInvitDescription) &&
                Objects.equals(mGpInvitUnit, that.mGpInvitUnit);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(mGpInvitRecid, mGpInvitName, mGpInvitDescription, mGpInvitPricenet, mGpInvitAmount, mGpInvitUnit, mGpInvitVat, mGpInvitPriceamountnet, mGpInvitPricevat, mGpInvitPricegross);
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "GP_INVIT_INVOICERECID", referencedColumnName = "GP_INVOICE_RECID", nullable = false)
    public GpInvoice getGpInvoiceByGpInvitInvoicerecid() {
        return mGpInvoiceByGpInvitInvoicerecid;
    }

    public void setGpInvoiceByGpInvitInvoicerecid(GpInvoice gpInvoiceByGpInvitInvoicerecid) {
        mGpInvoiceByGpInvitInvoicerecid = gpInvoiceByGpInvitInvoicerecid;
    }
}

public interface InvoiceRepository extends Repository<GpInvoice, Integer> {

    List<GpInvoice> findAll();

    GpInvoice findByGpInvoiceRecid(long id);

    void delete(GpInvoice gpInvoice);
}

@Service
public class InvoiceServiceImpl implements InvoiceService {

    @Autowired
    private InvoiceRepository mInvoiceRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<GpInvoice> findAll() {
        return mInvoiceRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public GpInvoice findById(long id) {
        return mInvoiceRepository.findByGpInvoiceRecid(id);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public GpInvoice delete(long id) {
        GpInvoice gpInvoice = findById(id);
        if (gpInvoice != null) {
            mInvoiceRepository.delete(gpInvoice);
        }
        return gpInvoice;
    }
}

@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/invoice")
public class InvoiceController {

    @Autowired
    private InvoiceService mInvoiceService;

    @GetMapping(path = "/all")
    public List findAllInvoices() {
        return mInvoiceService.findAll();
    }

    @DeleteMapping(path = {"/{id}"})
    public GpInvoice delete(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
        return mInvoiceService.delete(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer is in the question. What is wrong is precisely that you don't use JsonIgnore (or another way), and are thus asking Jackson to serialize a recursive data structure: it thus tries to serialize a contractor, and thus serializes its invoices, and thus serializes their contractor, and thus serializes their invoices, and thus serializes their contractor, etc. etc.

Comment: So it is impossible to get data about contractor? With JsonIgnore on contractor I got all data about invoice and all invoice item with data. Without JsonIgnore i got a lot of contractor so it is normally, I should not get one contractor?

Comment: Sure it is. Just add JsonIgnore to the list of invoices of the contractor. Or better, use DTOs.

Comment: I added JsonIgnore in correct places and now it is working as I wanted :)

Comment: You should really consider using DTOs.